# relation between confidence interval and likelihood function

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I once meet the following question,which is also listed by book written by Cosma Rohilla Shalizi

```
what is the relation between between confidence intervals and the likelihood function.
```

I am not very clear how to connect these two concepts?

Comment: I don't see any direct need for the first two tags in that list.

Answer (score 2):

Many confidence intervals are derived from the Fisher Information or directly from the likelihood function for a parameter of interest. Fisher information is of course based on the likelihood function as well. Let $\hat{\theta}$ denote the maximum likelihood estimator of our parameter of interest.  Here are four intervals based on the the likelihood function.

One asymptotic confidence interval: could be defined as:

$
S = \{\theta \in \Omega: \sqrt{nI(\theta)}|\hat{\theta}-\theta|<z_{\alpha/2}\}
$

Another by substituting in $I(\hat{\theta})$ for ${I(\theta)}$ and rewriting in a different form:

$
\left(\hat{\theta} \pm \frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{nI(\hat{\theta})}}\right)
$

Or we could use the observed Fisher Information, $-l_n^{''}(\hat{\theta})$, where $l_n^{''}$ is the second derivative of the log likelihood function, to get another interval:

$
\left(\hat{\theta} \pm \frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{-l_n^{''}(\hat{\theta})}}\right)
$

And a fourth interval, called profile confidence intervals is formed by:

$
S = \{\theta \in \Omega: 2l_n(\hat{\theta})-2l_n(\theta)<z_{\alpha/2}\}
$

which typically must be solved computationally.

So for example in the case of a sequence of iid normal variables in which we want a 95% CI for $\theta = \mu$, we could use:

$
\left(\hat{\theta} \pm \frac{z_{\alpha/2}}{\sqrt{nI(\theta})}\right)
$

and since $I(\theta)$ is $\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$ and $\hat{\theta}=\bar{x}$ we get:

$
\left(\bar{x} \pm \frac{z_{\alpha/2}*\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)
$

which is your famous CI equation based on Fisher information (an thus the likelihood function).

I skipped some details so let me know if you want any filled in or see Theoretical Statistics by Keener (2010).

Comment: This looks like a good overview, but aren't the profile intervals based on quantiles of chi-squared distributions? Perhaps you could also clarify the various meanings of "$z_{\alpha/2}$" appearing in your answer (as well as stating what your other variables mean, such as "$n$" and "$\alpha$") and tell us explicitly whether $\theta$ is univariate or a vector parameter. Concerning the first proposal: how can this deserve to be called a "confidence interval" when it explicitly requires the (true but unknown) value of $\theta$ for its calculation? Finally, please check the last formula.

Comment: This seems to be a great answer to me as far as I can tell. My only concern is that it might have been too technical for the original question. A simple answer might have been to say that information is the measure of how confident you are in your estimates. The more information you have the tighter your confidence intervals will be.

Comment: The profile confidence interval are based on Wilk's likelihood ratio statistic: $W=2\log L(\widehat{\theta})-2\log L(\theta) \sim \chi_p^2$ (for a scalar parameter $\theta$, $p = 1$). So the critical value is $\chi^2_{1,1-\alpha}$, not $z_{\alpha/2}$.